# How to print/extract information listed under a column from two dimensional array in Perl?

Tags: perl, arrays, data-structures

I have a output file which is a two dimensional array (this file was output generated after running script written to produce 2D array) and I have to read information under a particular column, say column 1. In other words, how do I read and print out information listed, corresponding to all the rows, under column 1.

Any suggestions?

```
__DATA__
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
  93  48 57 66 52 74 33 22 91
```

From the above data I want to extract information column wise, say if I want information from column 1, I should be able to list only the following output.
want to list Then I want

OUTPUT:

```
1
A
93
```

Comment: Please show what the file looks like - at least a piece of it.

Comment: Also, if the 2D array was originally created by Perl, then you could cut out the middleman altogether. Use a module like `Storable` to save a reference to the array to a file and then unfreeze it later. It's easy and quite fast. I use this occasionally for things that are too small to require a proper database solution.

Comment: @Sinan & Shubster: is the headers column (c0 c1 c2 etc) really in the data file, or did Shubster write that in simply to make clear where the columns are? In Shubster's version, it wasn't clear to me.

Comment: @Telemachus: The columns were not there in data file. I wrote it to make clear where columns were.

Comment: @Telemachus it wasn't clear to me either. However, if shubster will not format his posts unambiguously, I will interpret everything that follows `__DATA__` as the data. However, the fact that his sample output shows `c0` leads me to believe my assumption is correct.

Comment: @shubster when asked to show input, show input. Nothing more, nothing less. Otherwise, the reader might be confused (like I was in this case).

Comment: @Sinan: that was my instinct as well (in which case, some of the solutions below are no good), but I couldn't quite be sure.

Comment: Nobody's fault, really, but for the record: argh.

Comment: @Sinan & Telemachus: my bad if the 'c#' in input confused you. I was just trying to show what I meant when I say information stored under 'c0' 'c1' and so on.

Comment: @Shubster: it's not the end of the world, but many data files have headers as a first line, and the row1, row2, etc. was possible as well. If those had been there, the solution would have needed to be different. Again, not the end of the world.

Comment: @Telemachus agreed ... no biggie in the grand scheme of things but @shubster it makes everyone's life easier to show the literal input without any embellishments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Final version after all corrections:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $column_to_show = 0;

while ( <DATA> ) {
    last unless /\S/;
    print +(split)[$column_to_show], "\n";
}

__DATA__
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
  93  48 57 66 52 74 33 22 91
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> u
1
A
93
```

**Explanation of `print +(split)[$column_to_show], "\n";`:**

[`perldoc -f split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

> Splits the string EXPR into a list of strings and returns that list.
>   ...
>   If EXPR is omitted, splits the $_  string. If PATTERN is also omitted, 
>   splits on whitespace (after skipping any leading whitespace).

So: `(split)[3]` selects the fourth element of the list returned by `split`. The `+` in front of `(split)` is necessary to help `perl` parse the expression correctly. See [`perldoc -f print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html):

> Also be careful not to follow the
>   print keyword with a left parenthesis
>   unless you want the corresponding
>   right parenthesis to terminate the
>   arguments to the print — interpose a `+` 
>   or put parentheses around all the
>   arguments.

I thoroughly recommend every Perl programmer to occasionally skim through all of the documentation [perldoc perltoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/index.html). It is on your computer.

Comment: @Sinan: Your code is valid if I would have a 2D array and want to print out information in columns, but no I don't instead I have an output file. I have a file which has information in the form of two dimensional array (i.e. it is an output(file) of a script written to print out a 2D array). I have to read this file and extract information. And, I only want to extract the values listed, say under column 1. hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @Sinan: Can you explain " print +(split)[$column_to_show]; " with a comment. thanks.

Comment: @Sinan Unur:  I read both the documentations. I know split function and have also used it many a times. What I didnt know was 'split[column_to_print]'. Do square brackets signify something special? Why does 'split()' give error?

Comment: @Sinan: and I am learning a lot from your answers. just wanted to say thanks :).

Comment: @shubster You are welcome, but read carefully .. split() and (split) are two different things. Square brackets, as always, hold the index. The code you are asking about is equivalent to: **`my @result = split; print $result[$column_to_show], "\n";`**.

Answer (score 3):

```
my $line ;

foreach $line (@DATA)
{
   my @DATA1 = split( / +/, "$line" );
   print "first element of array is $DATA1[0]";        
}


__DATA__

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
 A   B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
 93  48 57 66 52 74 33 22 91
```

OUTPUT:-

```
 1
 A
 93
```

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with this code. Basically I load the data into an array of arrays

Each line is a reference to a row.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;    

my $TwoDimArray;
while (my $line=<DATA>) {
   push @$TwoDimArray, [split(/,/,$line)];
};

for my $column (0..2) {
   print "[$column,0] : " . $TwoDimArray->[0]->[$column] ."\n";
   print "[$column,1] : " . $TwoDimArray->[1]->[$column] ."\n";
   print "\n";
}

__DATA__
1,2,3,04,05,06
7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Answer (score 1):

The map function is your friend:

```
open FILE, "data.txt";
while ($line = <FILE>) {
   chomp($line);
   push @data, [split /[, ]+/, $line];
}
close FILE;

@column1 = map {$$_[0]} @data;

print "@column1\n";
```

And in data.txt something like:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
13, 14, 15, 16
```

Comment: Eric: this answer is quite helpful. Helen

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne '@F = split /\s+/ and print $F[1]'
```

Comment: The manual `@F=...` was based on an interpretation of the input from  an earlier version of the question.  With the new, better-specified input, `perl -alne 'print $F[0]'` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you want:

```
use English qw<$OS_ERROR>; # Or just use $! 
use IO::Handle;

my @columns;

open my $fh, '<', 'columns.dat' or die "I'm dead. $OS_ERROR";
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) { 
    my @cols = split /\s+/, $line;
    $columns[$_][$fh->input_line_number()-1] = $cols[$_] foreach 0..$#cols;
}
$fh->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access them directly by element.

```
$arrays[0][0] = 1;
$arrays[0][1] = 2;
$arrays[1][0] = 3;
$arrays[1][1] = 4;

for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#{$arrays[1]}; $i++) {
    print "row for $i\n";
    print "\tfrom first array: " . $arrays[0][$i] . "\n";
    print "\tfrom second array: " . $arrays[1][$i] . "\n";
}
```

prints

```
row for 0
    from first array: 1
    from second array: 3
row for 1
    from first array: 2
    from second array: 4
```